# Will ios terminate the app running in background after a specific time?

Tags: ios, ios5, core-location, uiapplicationdelegate, background-task

I am using core location framework inside my application and I set the location string in UIBackgroundMode or Required background modes(in Xcode 4.2) for getting the updated location from `didUpdateToLocation` method when app is running in background and also sending this updated location to server by hitting the specific link inside `didUpdateToLocation` method of core location framework.

My question is that will the app be terminated after some time when running in background or not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there is no specific time defined for this.But app will definitely terminate based upon certain parameter - battery drain, memory footprint issue etc.

In developer documentation it is clearly mentioned - "The system keeps suspended apps in memory for as long as possible, removing them only when the amount of free memory gets low. Remaining in memory means that subsequent launches of your app are much faster."

Go through this for complete details -
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Comment: Thanks and this link is very useful. And one more question i want to ask that will we required any event handling inside didUpdateToLocation method because "Sleep when not handling events" is stated in the given document of the above link when app is in background state.

Comment: if you are interested in getting location even if it is in sleep then you need to use this, else nothing specific.

Comment: When the app goes in sleep state?

Comment: in documentation it is stated that UIBackgroundMode(location) will notify the app when location is update when app is in background. I think if app sleeps and location updates then app notified and it goes to background state again am i true?

Comment: You can use Significant Change Location Service to update location in background as well in kill state too.  Please refer apple document guide for SCLS.

Answer (score 8):

I am sure it is not useful for the author because the question was asked in June 2012 and I am giving an answer in June 2019. This answer maybe is useful for other users.

**I am posting this answer because Everyone is said that it is OS default behaviour, We can not change it....bla....bla.**

> Recently, I was working with the same requirement. After 2-3 week hard
> work, I did it. For other users, I create a helper class for it. My
> app will never be killed by OS until the location tracking enabled.
>
> You can also verify that OS will never kill [this app tracking app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/capchur-journal-diary/id1440569415)

Use [HSLocationManager](https://github.com/IMHitesh/HSLocationManager) for infinite location tracking in the active and inactive state.

Refer my app which is available in the app store(App will never kill by OS if location tracking is enabled)

> Location manager that allows getting background location updates every
> n seconds with desired location accuracy.
>
> **Advantage:**
>
> - OS will never kill our app if the location manager is currently
>   running.
> - Give periodically location update when it required(range is between 2 -
>   170 seconds (limited by max allowed background task time))
> - Customizable location accuracy and time period.
> - Low memory consumption(Singleton class)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.

Working on similar functionality for and have converted your code to a lib that can be used with cross-platform app development.

You my friend legend.

This needs more upvotes

Comment: Interesting use for background location updates. I wonder why this doesn't have more upvotes

Answer (score 3):

iOS app may get terminated due to following reasons:

1. **Watchdog Timeout**

> As you’re probably aware, since iOS 4.x, most of the time when you
>       quit an iOS app, the app isn’t terminated – instead, it’s sent to
>       the background.
>
> ```
> However, there are times when the OS will terminate your app and
> generate a crash log if the app didn’t respond fast enough. These
> events correspond with the implementation of the following
> UIApplicationDelegate methods:
>
>    - application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
>    - applicationWillResignActive:
>    - applicationDidEnterBackground:
>    - applicationWillEnterForeground:
>    - applicationDidBecomeActive:
>    - applicationWillTerminate:
> ```
>
> In all of the above methods, the app gets a limited amount of time
>       to finish its processing. If the app takes too long, the OS will
>       terminate the app.

2. **User Force-Quit**

> iOS 4.x supports multitasking. If an app blocks the UI and stops
>   responding, the user can double-tap the Home button from the Home
>   screen and terminate the app.
>
> Note: You may have noticed that when you double-tap the Home button,
>   you also get a list of all the applications you’ve run in the past.
>   Those apps are not necessarily running, nor are they necessarily
>   suspended.
>
> Usually an app gets about 10 minutes to stay in the background once
>   the user hits the Home button, and then it gets terminated
>   automatically by the OS. So the list of apps that you see by
>   double-tapping the Home button is only a list of past app runs.

3. **Low Memory Termination**

> When subclassing UIViewController, you may have noticed the
>   didReceiveMemoryWarning method.
>
> Any app that is running in the foreground has the highest priority in
>   terms of accessing and using memory. However, that does not mean the
>   app gets all the available memory on the device – each app gets a
>   portion of the available memory.
>
> When total memory consumption hits a certain level, the OS sends out a
>   UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification notification. At the
>   same time, didReceiveMemoryWarning is invoked for the app.
>
> At this point, so that your app continues to run properly, the OS
>   begins terminating apps in the background to free some memory. Once
>   all background apps are terminated, if your app still needs more
>   memory, the OS terminates your app.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that the background location updates will work for several hours. But if I go to a place without reception the device will stop to send GPS updates it wont start when I go to a place with reception. This occurs after approximately 30min.

But if I add this, in iOS6, the app won't terminate

```
[locationManager setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:NO];
```

Comment: Beware that you're bypassing an optimisation. Together with the activityType, the system will intelligently stop delivering location data to your app (if you've set fitness activityType and you don't move for more then a couple of minutes, then pause the device effort to track you until you start moving again...), it also means the radios are powered down, saving battery life. It will indeed continue delivering location data if you set the manager to never pause, but in this case you're more likely to be terminated by iOS sooner since the device is doing more work.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is pretty much no. Read below though for in depth.

Since multitasking has been enabled on iOS devices that a)your app gets allocated amount of memory and b)the device limits the amount of tasks, that is applications using memory, that occur at any given time. If you take an iOS device and open several apps you'll begin to notice that the app you opened first *may* have been terminated and reload from the `viewDidLoad`.

Generally it's safe to say if your app is a recently opened app (or even on a phone where someone clears the multitasking menu often) that the device will **not** terminate your application in the background.