# App silently terminating while suspended. (User presses lock button while on my app)

Tags: ios, xcode, appdelegate

I am aware of the documentation below but even after reading it I still don't seem to understand why it would be terminating my app.

> Apps must be prepared for termination to happen at any time and should not wait to save user data or perform other critical tasks. System-initiated termination is a normal part of an app’s life cycle. The system usually terminates apps so that it can reclaim memory and make room for other apps being launched by the user, but the system may also terminate apps that are misbehaving or not responding to events in a timely manner.
>   Suspended apps receive no notification when they are terminated; the system kills the process and reclaims the corresponding memory. If an app is currently running in the background and not suspended, the system calls the applicationWillTerminate: of its app delegate prior to termination. The system does not call this method when the device reboots.
>   In addition to the system terminating your app, the user can terminate your app explicitly using the multitasking UI. User-initiated termination has the same effect as terminating a suspended app. The app’s process is killed and no notification is sent to the app.

I only had my one app in the background so I can't imagine that it would have terminated my app because it needed more memory. But I noticed that the doc also says that apps may be terminated if they misbehave, does anybody know what exactly this means? Am I missing something in my info.plist? Am I violating some sort of protocol that is forcing my app to be terminated? It also always seems to be very random when it terminates my app, it could be as little as 15 mins or it could be an 1 hour.

I also had a look around and saw this thread here

[Will ios terminate the app running in background after a specific time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926269/will-ios-terminate-the-app-running-in-background-after-a-specific-time)

I would understand If my app was to be terminated while in the background and the user was to do other things in the meantime but I don't see why it would be terminated when it was suspended from the lock button specifically. Especially when I'm testing this on a iphone 6s with only my app in memory.

Comment: Are you using any background modes?  If not then iOS may have just decided your app wasn't being used and it could be purged from memory.  Even if you aren't running other apps, the operating system is running tasks

Comment: @Paulw11 background modes are background fetch and remote notifications. I understand that it "could" be purged from memory but I really doubt that it would have purged my app because it needed more memory or any of reason they have listed in their documenation. Also, if it was so easily purged without a solid reason that would contradict apple's motivation to leave apps in memory as oppose to terminating them always.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the crash logs? There are some things that will cause you to be terminated while backgrounding like making OpenGL calls when you're not on screen.

Or, maybe there's a bug in your app that's making it crash and the system isn't actually terminating you. Hook up the device, go to Xcode>Window>Devices & Simulators and look at the device logs for your device at the time of the crash.

That might give you a clue.

Comment: I have checked my crash logs already and unfortunately no luck there, it doesn't seem like my app is crashing.

Comment: If the system is killing your app there will also be a message in the system console log.